# Категория состояния -- имя?

Tags: грамматика, морфология

В Википедии есть [статья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) "Имя состояния". Составлена она, на мой взгляд, сомнительно, но тем не менее: считаете ли вы категорию состояния именем?

Я думаю, что КГ не имя, так как ее нельзя причислить к классу слов, обладающих склонением (исходя из соответствующего определения грамматического имени).

P. S. Каково ваше отношение к концепции В. В. Бабайцевой и Л. Д. Чесноковой в целом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спор чисто терминологический. Само понятие "категория состояния" до сих пор вызывает полемику. 
Но если уж мы в нашей модели грамматики принимаем категорию состояния как данность, то к чему её отнести? Не к глаголу же? Там вообще совершенно другие категорийные типы

А в русском (и вообще во всех известных мне языках) все категории представлены как две такие группы - категории имени и категории глагола.
Всё это есть в вики, начиная отсюда
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

и отсюда.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F

Ну или вводить самостоятельную, третью группу категорий, специально для категории состояния. Но это еще более противоречивый и неблагодарный путь.

(+)
Если непонятно, начните с того, что в общей лингвистике принято все знаменательные слова относить либо к именам, либо к действиям (глаголам). 
Деление это - не объективная данность, это модель человеческого восприятия, но она, модель эта, реально работает. И в рамках этой модели "категория состояния", если мы принимаем её как данность, - это, конечно, имя, никак не глагол. Наречие же, строго говоря, это тоже имя, только в методических целях о том обычно не говорят.

Comment: А что вы называете именем? Ведь КС, а тем более наречие не обладает склонением, поэтому ни о каком противопоставлении глаголу как классу речи быть не может.

Comment: А я писал. И ссылки давал. Имя называет/обозначает объект/свойство/аттрибут и т. п.*. Все знаменательные части речи делятся на имена и глаголы. Все, что не глагол - все имя.  Склонение и проч - лишь внешние признаки ***части*** имен. Имя - понятие общей лингвистики, в то время как все эти склонения - свойство отдельных языков, в частности русского.

Comment: по первой ссылке белая страница, вторая вроде не говорит об обязательном делении имена и неимена. Ладно, спасибо.

Comment: Я тоже не говорю об обязательности. Но так сложилось. Ссылка у меня работает. Но это всего лишь оглавление. "Категория:Грамматические категории". И там представлено только "категория имени" и "категория глагола".

Comment: может, с телефона некорректно

Answer (score 2):

Можно говорить **о двух основных категориях**:  о категории имени и о категории процесса (действия). Имя – это название предмета (существительное) или название непроцессуального признака (прилагательное), а глагол – это название процессуального признака (действия).

По-моему, **категория состояния ближе к процессу, чем к имени.** Слова категории состояния иначе называются предикатами или безлично-предикативными словами. Глаголы и слова категории состояния имеют сходную синтаксическую функцию, являясь в предложение сказуемым, они составляют предикативную основу предложения.

С другой стороны, глаголы также могут называть **состояния** природы и живых существ, например: темнеть, грустить, болеть.

Поэтому **имя состояния – неудачное название для слов категории состояния**.  Наречия, которые относятся к этой группе, называют предикативными наречиями и отличают от обычных обстоятельственных наречий, например: Сегодня холодно. – Он ответил односложно и холодно.

Comment: *категория состояния ближе к процессу, чем к имени.* - какова валентность этого процесса (глагола)?